# setting redirect page for my Joomla website hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, joomla

I am using Joomla with IIS in my website, and now i am trying to set a 404 redirect page in my Joomla website, i could use htaccess to make this when i am using apache, but for this IIS its gets tricky it seems.

you can see my web.config file [here](http://goo.gl/fGhF1)

any suggestion would be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module available AFAIK - at least not for 1.6. But it is quite easy to do by yourself. You can use the solution in the joomla documentation. This is usable for any error code.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page

if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: /search');
exit;
}

The part behind the Location: is where you redirect to the page you want. e.g. /search in this case. The above is for 1.5, for 1.6 you need to use this:

if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') {
          header('Location: /search');
          exit;
  } ;

Answer (score 0):

in your IIS Console, right click on the website, goto the Custom Errors TAB,
scroll down to HTTP Error 404, Edit Properties, change the Message Type
to URL, and then type in the URL you want to change to.